# how to remove a tag and its contents using regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

$str = 'some text  tag *contents*   more text ';

My questions are:
How to retrieve content `tag <em>contents </em>` which is between `<MY_TAG> .. </MY_TAG>`?

And

How to remove `<MY_TAG>` and its contents from `$str`?

I am using PHP.

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder how many times the following answer is linked in any given day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: HTML parser blah blah blah... You know the drill.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `MY_TAG` can not be nested, try this to get the matches:

```
preg_match_all('/<MY_TAG>(.*?)<\/MY_TAG>/s', $str, $matches)
```

And to remove them, use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) instead.

Comment: @user187580: The *s* flag makes the `.` match line breaks. See http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: You had better set ungreedy with this pattern if you may find this tag in the string more than once. Otherwise you'll find that you convert this string

"This is <my_tag>a very</my_tag> important <my_tag>set</my_tag> line"

into "This is line"

Comment: @Don The `?` after the `*` does exactly the same.

Comment: And I looked right at this answer and did not see the ? modifier, whoops!

Answer (score 14):

For removal I ended up just using this:

```
$str = preg_replace('~<MY_TAG(.*?)</MY_TAG>~Usi', "", $str);
```

Using ~ instead of / for the delimiter solved errors being thrown because of the backslash in the end tag, which seemed to be an issue even with escaping.  Eliminating > from the opening tag allows for attributes or other characters and still gets the tag and all of its contents.

This only works where nesting is not a concern.

The `Usi` modifiers mean U = Ungreedy, s = include linebreak characters, i = case insensitive.

Comment: good job (y) work fine for span e.g $ptitle = preg_replace('~<span(.*?)</span>~Usi', "", $ptitleWithSpan);

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to use regular expressions for this. A much better solution would be to load your contents into a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument) and work on it using the DOM tree and standard DOM methods:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML('<root/>');
$document->documentElement->appendChild(
    $document->createFragment($myTextWithTags));

$MY_TAGs = $document->getElementsByTagName('MY_TAG');
foreach($MY_TAGs as $MY_TAG)
{
    $xmlContent = $document->saveXML($MY_TAG);
    /* work on $xmlContent here */

    /* as a further example: */
    $ems = $MY_TAG->getElementsByTagName('em');
    foreach($ems as $em)
    {
        $emphazisedText = $em->nodeValue;
        /* do your operations here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the only fully correct way to do this is not to use regular expressions, you can get what you want if you accept it won't handle all special cases:

```
preg_match("/<em[^>]*?>.*?</em>/i", $str, $match);
// Use this only if you aren't worried about nested tags.
// It will handle tags with attributes
```

And

```
preg_replace(""/<MY_TAG[^>]*?>.*?</MY_TAG>/i", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this function, it works for nested tags too, use true/false to exclude/include your tags. Found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
<?php
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) {

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags);
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]);
   
  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) {
    if($invert == FALSE) {
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
    else {
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
  }
  elseif($invert == FALSE) {
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
  }
  return $text;
}




// Sample text:
$text = '<b>sample</b> text with <div>tags</div>';

// Result for:
echo strip_tags_content($text);
// text with

// Result for:
echo strip_tags_content($text, '<b>');
// <b>sample</b> text with

// Result for:
echo strip_tags_content($text, '<b>', TRUE);
// text with <div>tags</div>
```