# How to scrape H2 and H3 tags from html page in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to get h2 and h3 tags as $var in php from this html code below:

```
<div class="main-info">
   <img class="iphone-img" alt="" src="https://www.myweb.com/securedImage.jsp">
        <div class="sub-info">
                <h2 class="model">iPhone 4S</h2>
                <h3 class="capacity color">16GB Black</h3>
          </div>
</div>
```

And I want this results:

```
echo $model; // Should echo:  'iPhone 4S'
echo $capacitycolour; // Should echo: '16GB Black'
```

I have tried with `preg_match`, `preg_match_all` and `getElementsByTagName` but no luck so far.

Here is the code I tried:

```
$pattern = '/[^\n]h2*[^\n]*/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_dump($matches);
```

and:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($data);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('sub-info');

$root = $doc->documentElement;
foreach($root->childNodes as $node){
    $attributes[$node->nodeName] = $node->nodeValue;
}

var_dump($attributes);
```

Comment: @Naruto: strip_tags()  will not help me to solve my problem. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381657/how-to-remove-a-tag-and-its-contents-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sub-info` is the class, not the tagname so your use of DOMDocument is flawed, you might be better using an XPath query.

```
$strhtml='<div class="main-info">
            <img class="iphone-img" alt="" src="https://www.myweb.com/securedImage.jsp?configcode=DTF9&size=120x120">
            <div class="sub-info">
                <h2 class="model">
                        iPhone 4S
                </h2>
                <h3 class="capacity color">
                    16GB Black 
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>';


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $strhtml );
$xpath=new DOMXPath( $doc );
$col=$xpath->query('//div[@class="sub-info"]/h2|//div[@class="sub-info"]/h3');
if( $col ){
    /* You could store results from query in an array */
    $tags=array();
    foreach( $col as $node ) {

        /* Simplest form to display results on separate lines, use br tag */
        echo $node->nodeValue . '<br />';

        /* Add tags to array - a rethink would be required if there are multiple h2 and h3 tags! */
        $tags[ $node->tagName ]=$node->nodeValue;

    }
    /* echo back results from array */
    echo $tags['h2'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo $tags['h3'];
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

For the future just try an online regex tester to verify your expressions.

For the H2-Tags, the following would work: `.*<h2.*>[\n\s]*(.*)` (despite no beeing the most optimal one)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [simple_html_dom.php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) before in many cases and works really well. It allows for CSS like selectors once you have loaded the document. Additionally, you can parse either from string, local file or URL! The following will give you an array of `Element`s:

```
$div = $html->find('div.sub-info');
$ret = $div[0]->find('h2, h3');
```

API reference: [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

*Warning:* Do not use RegEx to parse HTML, if you do see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) what will happen :)

Answer (score 0):

is that you Cyberboki?

check this.

```
$strhtml='<div class="main-info">
        <img class="iphone-img" alt="" src="https://www.myweb.com/securedImage.jsp?configcode=DTF9&size=120x120">
        <div class="sub-info">
            <h2 class="model">
                    iPhone 4S
            </h2>
            <h3 class="capacity color">
                16GB Black 
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>';
$new = preg_replace("/\s+/",' ',$strhtml);  
preg_match('/<h2 class="model">(.*?)<\/h2>/i', $new , $h2); 
preg_match('/<h3 class="capacity color">(.*?)<\/h3>/i', $new , $h3); 

echo "option 1";
echo "<br/>";
echo $h2[1];
echo "<br/>";
echo $h3[1];
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

    $ex = explode("\n",strip_tags($strhtml));   
    foreach($ex as $key){
        //echo $key;
        $line_out = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($key));
        if(strlen($line_out) > 0){
            $rr[] = trim($key);
        }
    }
echo "option 2";
echo "<br/>";       
echo $rr[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo $rr[1];        

result:
option 1
iPhone 4S
16GB Black

option 2
iPhone 4S
16GB Black
```

Regards,
iPhoneYeta